# How to create a [ ] border in html?

Tags: html, css

how do I create a border like the one in the image using HTML/CSS?

[image: how to create such border]

Thank you :)

Comment: Please show some effort first. Add some HTML/CSS code to show what you've tried so far. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  padding: 20px 20px 0;
}

.child {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: -30px 0 -10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Hello StackOverflow!
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes. It certainly help. How do it centre align the div then?

Comment: Didn't get you. The whole div `.parent` or `.child`?